# Expected else after guard statement, but else is there, why is it complaining?

Tags: swift

I am trying to do `PropertyListSerialization` as opposed to using just `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` so I changed my code for that. Now using `guard`, I have to give `else`. I am providing `else`. What mistake am I making in this line of code?

It says:

> Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition.

This line of code when using `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` was working fine. But this change to `PropertyListSerialization` is not working for me.

```
        guard
            let filePathValue = filePath,
//            let fileContentDictionary:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePathValue)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: filePathValue as URL),

        let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String:Any]]
            print(result!)

        else{
            return
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote print(result!) in between

Comment: Magically Yes,  would you please care to explain why printing(result!) doesn't give the issue. I want to print the result then, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `result` after that `else` block also if your response is `dictionary` then you need to cast the result of `propertyList(from:options:format:)` to `[String:Any]` not the `[[String:Any]]` because it is dictionary.

```
guard let filePathValue = filePath,
    //let fileContentDictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePathValue)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: filePathValue as URL),
    let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String:Any] //not [[String:Any]]
else {
    return
}
//Result is still optional
print(result!)
```

Now as of you have used `try?` your result is still optional so if you want result as non-optional then use `()` with `try?` like this.

```
guard let filePathValue = filePath,
    //let fileContentDictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePathValue)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: filePathValue as URL),
    let result = (try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil)) as? [String:Any] //not [[String:Any]]
else {
    return
}
//Now result is non-optional
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print(result!)` is a problem.

Remove it.

**Update:**

```
guard let filePathValue = filePath,
      //let fileContentDictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePathValue)
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: filePathValue as URL),
      let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String:Any]]
else {
    return
}

print(result!)
```

Comment: Please explain, why it is a problem, how can I print the result , if I want.

Answer (score 1):

The basic `guard-else` block looks like this:

```
guard `condition` else {
    `statements`
}
```

Example:

```
guard let name = optionalName else {
    // Value requirements not met, do something.
    // name isn't available here
    return
}
// Value requirements met, do something with name
// name is available here
// Rest of the code goes here
```

You have to consider `guard-else` as a single program control statement. No statements are made in between them. Only conditions are checked. You may have multiple conditions separated by commas (,).

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) it says:

> Any constants or variables assigned a value from an optional binding
>   declaration in a guard statement condition can be used for the rest of
>   the guard statement’s enclosing scope.